# Parsing a file of email adresses to set email recipients

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which parses a list of email addresses and send a mail to them.

The file is formatted this way:

```
a.a@domain.com
b.b@domain.com
c.c@domain.com
...
```

I figured something like:

```
$recipients = Get-Content -Path MY_FILE.txt

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$mail.To = $recipients   # here's the problem
$mail.Subject = "MY_SUBJECT"
$mail.HTMLBody = "MY_HTML_BODY"
$mail.Send()
```

My problem, as you can see is: how can I assign the addresses in `$recipients` to `$mail.To`?

Comment: Do you want to send one mail to multiple recipients at once, or a separate mail for each recipient?

Comment: One mail to multiple at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to):

> ### MailItem.To Property (Outlook)
>
> Returns or sets a ***semicolon-delimited String list of display names*** for the To recipients for the Outlook item.
>   Read/write.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Remarks
>
> ***This property contains the display names only.*** The To property corresponds to the MAPI property PidTagDisplayTo. ***The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property.***

Emphasis mine.

To send one mail to all recipients change this line:

```
$mail.To = $recipients
```

into this:

```
foreach ($addr in $recipients) {
    $mail.Recipients.Add($addr)
}
```

and the code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send every address in your file a separate email do it this way:

```
$recipients = Get-Content -Path MY_FILE.txt
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

ForEach ($recipient in $recipients) {
    $mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.To = $recipient
    $mail.Subject = "MY_SUBJECT"
    $mail.HTMLBody = "MY_HTML_BODY"
    $mail.Send()
}
```

Also make sure you close the COM Object by adding the following to the end of your file:

```
$outlook.Quit() 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outlook) | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$file = "$PSScriptRoot\MY_FILE.txt"

# Add a List of recipients
$to = @()
foreach ($email in (Get-Content $file)) {
    $to += "$email;"
}
Write-Host "Complete recipient-list: $to"


$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "$to"
$mail.Subject = "MY_SUBJECT"
$mail.HTMLBody = "MY_HTML_BODY"
$mail.Send()
```